# Mysql Cluster Restore A Backup To A Database With A Different Configuration

Tags: mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I have an mysql cluster which have 4 data nodes and number of replicas is 2. So I have 2 node groups with 2 data nodes in a every node group.

I planing to add 4 data nodes more to this cluster. After adding nodes i can reorganize partitions but I have to do this for every table.

Is it possible to restore a backup which was created from 4 data nodes to cluster that have 8 data nodes?

Comment: Which Mysql Cluster version are you using?  (Percona, Fabric, NDB?)

Comment: Using NDB Cluster